# Arrange Checkbox and Radio button from vertical to horizontal alignment on new form on SharePoint online list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery, choice-field

We have multiple checkbox & radio buttons columns on our SharePoint online list form. We want to change the display of all checkbox & radio button horizontally.

We tried below script, but all checkbox & radio buttons are showing in one line (please refer screenshot below). We want horizontal alignments based columns.

Any suggestions on how to do it?

Thanks

[image]

Script tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function()
{
  var firstRadio = $j(".ms-RadioText:eq(0)");
  $j(".ms-RadioText:gt(0)").appendTo($j(firstRadio));
});
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Are there 3 choice columns? Radio, Test1 and test2??

Comment: Yes, Three are Choice columns only. We tried above script and buttons are displaying as per screenshots.

Comment: Try below code and let me know if this works...replace the field name as per the display name of your radio choice field.

Answer (score 0):

**For Radio buttons**:

Try below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var reBuildTR = $('<tr></tr>').append("<th></th>");

        //update Test1 as your field name
        $('table[id^="Test1"]').find('td').each(function () {
            $(reBuildTR).append($(this));
        })
        $('table[id^="Test1"]').html("").append(reBuildTR);
    })
</script>
```

**For Checkboxes**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        ArrangeCheckBoxes("Test1");
        ArrangeCheckBoxes("test 2");
    });
    function ArrangeCheckBoxes(checkboxFieldName) {  
        var len = $("table[id^='" + checkboxFieldName + "'] tbody tr td .ms-RadioText").length;  
        temp = len - 1;  
        count = 0;  
        var startingElement;  
        for (i = 0; i < len; i = i + 4) {  
            if (count == temp) break;  
            startingElement = $("table[id^='" + checkboxFieldName + "'] tbody tr td .ms-RadioText:eq(" + i + ")").closest('tr');
            count++;  
            for (j = i + 1; j <= i + 3; j++) {  
                if (count == temp) break;  
                $("table[id^='" + checkboxFieldName + "'] tbody tr td .ms-RadioText:eq(" + (j) + ")").closest('td').appendTo(startingElement);  
                count++;  
            }  
        }  
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Ganesh, We tied your script. Alignments changed vertical. But we want change all checkbox & radio button (three columns(Radio, Test1 & Test 2) ) from vertical to horizontally alignments. Kindly suggest.

Comment: I have updated my answer. try it for multi-select choice (checkboxes) field. Pass display name of your fields to the `ArrangeCheckBoxes()` function.

Comment: I tried your update script with by adding script editor web part on new form page. But its not working Ganesh. Where i need to give columns (or) ID names? where i need to Usage columns. Sorry i am new to coding part. Kindly suggest more please.

Comment: Try updated code. you need to pass the display name (name on the form) of your field at `$(function () {
        ArrangeCheckBoxes("Test1");
        ArrangeCheckBoxes("test 2");
    });`

Comment: Ganesh, i had given my display column name on your code, but still no change. is anything i am doing wrong? I just copy your script and placed on my new list form.

Comment: Are you getting any error in console? Can you please add a breakpoint at line `temp = len - 1;` and check what is the value of `len` variable??

Comment: I had attached console screenshot for your reference. Kindly check please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104452/discussion-between-murali-kuruva-and-ganesh-sanap).

Comment: Have you tried adding this code in script editor webpart and not directly from console? Also make sure you have added jQuery file reference in your code (seems like jquery file is not loaded. so, it will throw an `$` not found error).